# C array decay disambiguation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When I declare `int a[5][3];` what exactly is `a[2]`, is it a pointer to array or does it decays to a pointer to int `a[2][0]`.
I want to talk about 2D arrays, and I am concerned in decay whether `a[2]` decays or not when used independently.

Comment: `a[2]` is an array of 3 `int`. It will decay to pointer to its first element, i.e. `a[2][0]` except in some cases like when used with `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `a[2]` is an array of 3 int's.

However if you are looking for Array decaying then you can look for this [what is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

> I want to talk about 2D arrays, and I am concerned in decay whether
>   a[2] decays or not when used independently.

It will not decay all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, `a[2]` denotes an array of 3 `int`s. It does not decay to a pointer all by itself. It has the type information.